# Exporting for Linux, OS.is_debug_build() is always true

Tags: godot

I'm trying to export my Godot game server with the Linux/X11 preset (plus unchecking "Export with Debug") but calling OS.is_debug_build() is still returning true.

Is there something I'm missing to be able to export as release? Is there another way to check if it's running in debug/release?

I'm using Godot version 3.4.4.

Comment: What version of Godot are you using?

Comment: I'm using v3.4.4